# PHPUnit - How to test a specific row in a table

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm busy writing a test suite and need to make sure that a particular table update is happening.

From the PHPUnit manual I see how to use getConnection() and to test a table against an expected table.

This is not ideal for me as in the future more tests will be added that will almost certainly result in my fixture changing, which will mean that the expected table will also need to be maintained.

Rather I want to use my current fixture, run a method that updates it, and then check that the specific user has been blacklisted.

Comment: Tip: sharing fixtures between tests is a bad idea. Also know that if you're checking the result you're not doing a unit test - that's a functional test. A unit test would assert, for example, that a mocked database is called with the command to insert/update the relevant row, nothing else.

Comment: PHPUnit is for testing code, not data.  You need to look at how to decouple the business logic of your design from whatever underlying storage mechanism you're using.

Comment: You might also want to look at DbUnit to help PHPUnit with the testing you are looking to do.